# JS images not changing, error: anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Easy one for you guys :) not sure why, but my img are not changing as they supposed to. Chrome gives me error: starting(anonymous function). I've checked my code so many times, cant figure out whats wrong, please help.

```
var pictures = new Array(6);
    var curPic = 0;
    var begin;
    pictures[0] = 'puppy0.gif';
    pictures[1] = 'puppy1.gif';
    pictures[2] = 'puppy2.gif';
    pictures[3] = 'puppy3.gif';
    pictures[4] = 'puppy4.gif';
    pictures[5] = 'puppy5.gif';
    function starting(){
        if(curPic = 5)
            curPic = 0;
        else
            ++curPic;
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = pictures[curPic].src;
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = pictures[curPic];
    }

    function anima(){
        if(begin)
            clearInterval(begin);
        begin = setInterval("starting()", 90);
    }

<body>
<img src="puppy1.gif" id="pics">
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="anima();">
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="clearInterval(begin);">
```

Images are in the same folder as index.html file.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
setInterval(starting, 90);
```

instead of

```
setInterval("starting()", 90);
```

modify your js

```
var pictures = new Array(6);
    var curPic = 0;
    var begin;
    pictures[0] = 'puppy0.gif';
    pictures[1] = 'puppy1.gif';
    pictures[2] = 'puppy2.gif';
    pictures[3] = 'puppy3.gif';
    pictures[4] = 'puppy4.gif';
    pictures[5] = 'puppy5.gif';
    function starting(){
        if(curPic = 5)
            curPic = 0;
        else
            ++curPic;
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = pictures[curPic];
    }

    function anima(){
        begin = setInterval(starting, 90);
    }
```

now try

Comment: didint help. still does same, changes one pic only: from puppy1 to puppy0 ... looks like function doesnt work at all.

Comment: @MrPaulius in which tag you want to display image?

Comment: @Satish_Sharma tag? hmz. Just need those pics changing every 90ms.

Comment: remove "if(begin)
            clearInterval(begin);" in anima function

Answer (score 2):

Remove this - `pictures[curPic].src`

```
function starting(){
    if(curPic = 5)
        curPic = 0;
    else
        ++curPic;
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = pictures[curPic];
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = pictures[curPic];
}
```

Comment: didint help. still does same, changes one pic only: from puppy1 to puppy0 ... looks like function doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here, when you define the function to be called by the `setInterval`. Try this way:

```
setInterval(starting, 90);
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Also, this doesn't exist. Remove the `.src` (or even better, remove the whole line, which is repeated anyway):

```
pictures[curPic].src
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/QU2bX/

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 2px dotted brown;
    text-align: center;
}
img,input,div {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(20,20,20,0.5);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" id="pic"/>
    <hr/>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="init();"/>
    <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="abort();"/>
    <script>
    var l = 6;
    var pictures = new Array(l);
    var c = 0;
    var img = document.querySelector('#pic');

    for(var i=0;i<l;i++) {
        pictures[i] = 'http://placehold.it/350x' + parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    }

    console.log(pictures);

    img.src= pictures[c];

    function animate() {
        img.src= pictures[c];
        if(c == l-1) {c = -1;}
        c += 1;
    }

    function init() {
        window.timer = setInterval(animate,1000);
    }
    function abort() {
        if(window.timer) {clearInterval(timer);}
    }
    </script>
</body>
```